# Should between-subject factors be included as random slopes for item in a mixed effects model?

Tags: r, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

My data look like this: The dependent variable is score on a language task (*numerical*). I have $2$ **between subject** variables:

1. age (young vs old: *categorical*)
2. language (monolingual vs. bilingual: *categorical*)

Then, I have $3$ **within-subject** variables (task conditions):

1. verb type (2 values: *categorical*)
2. focus (2 values: *categorical*)
3. definiteness (2 values: *categorical*)

There are two random effects:

1. subject
2. item

I run an `lmer` model in R.  I want to include random intercepts and random slopes.

**Question:** Does it make sense to include random slopes for within-subject (so `verbtype`, `focus` and `definiteness`) factors for RE subject and random slopes for between-subject factor (so `age` and `language`) for RE item?

If yes, the model would look like this, so all factors as random slopes for both random effects:

```
lmer(score ~ age * language * verbtype * focus * definiteness + 
             (1+age+language+verbtype+focus+definiteness|subject) + 
             (1+age+language+verbtype+focus+definiteness|item), 
     data)
```

Intuitively, I feel like it does not make sense to include between-subject factors (`age` and `language`) as random slopes for subject and between-item factors (`verbtype`, `focus` and `definiteness`) as random slopes for item. 
If this intuition is correct, the model would be:

```
lmer(score ~ age * language * verbtype * focus * definiteness + 
             (1+verbtype+focus+definiteness|subject) + (1+age+language|item), 
     data)
```

**Which one of these models makes more sense?**

Comment: +1. Your intuition is correct. The second model is correct (assuming that all three within-subject factors are between-item).

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245960/between-subject-variable-in-mixed-effect-model). In short, "a model specifying random slopes for a between subjects variable would be unidentifiable." But you can still include within-subject factors as random slopes for subject RE.