# Using random effects for a between-subjects variable to assess variability in a mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, variability

#### I want to use a mixed model to test random effects for between subject factors.

Similar questions have been covered before, with answers that it can be done using lme4. (See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245960/between-subject-variable-in-mixed-effect-model) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408973/can-we-really-assign-random-slopes-to-between-subject-effects-in-a-mixed-effects) for some excellent examples.)

However, I want to know if this is possible in the specific context below, to test a theoretical question on variability (I think this question does not overlap with the others).

#### My data

One **dependent variable** of task score.

Two **between-subject variables**

- Group (disease or healthy)
- Comorbidity (a sum of 7 possible simultaneous health conditions)

One **within-subject variable**

- Task (4 tasks)

(In summary, each subject did all 4 tasks, belongs to only one group, and has only one comorbidity score)

#### Possible models

So far, I think this model should work

```
model.1 <- lmer (TaskScore ~ 
                               1 + Group + Task + Group*Task + Comorbidity       # fixed effects
                              (1|Subject) + (1 + Task|Subject),                  # random effects
                               data)
```

I interpret the random effects as follows

- (1|Subject) Each subject is expected to be different compared to other subjects, across the tasks (some subjects have low scores across tasks, others have high scores across tasks), thus this measures ***between-subject variability***
- (1 + Task|Subject) Each subject is also expected to be different on each task (each person has low scores on some tasks and high scores on other tasks), thus this measures ***within-subject variability***

However, I also want to measure the following two questions,

- Whether subjects are more different (i.e, ***between-subject variability is higher***) in one group than another, specified below as (1 + Group|Subject)
- Whether each subject is more different across tasks (i.e, ***within-subject variability is higher***) in one group than another, specified below as (1 + Group*Task|Subject)

```
model.2 <- lmer (TaskScore ~ 
                               1 + Group + Task + Group*Task + Comorbidity       # fixed effects
                              (1|Subject) + (1 + Task|Subject),                  # random effects
                              (1 + Group|Subject) + (1 + Group*Task|Subject),    # more random effects
                               data)
```

#### Question: How can I used a mixed effect model to test variability as outlined above?

First, does model 1 (and my interpretations of it) make sense?

Second, can I make the additions in model 2?

(If not, how can I adapt model 1 to test my questions of interest? Should I be using a different technique altogether?)

Comment: In other words, the heterogeneity of variance between groups is what I am interested in modelling.

Comment: Thank you so much in advance to everyone who helps by answering. I really appreciate your time!